# What does := mean in pseudocode?

Tags: syntax, pseudocode

I am currently looking at pseudocode of a quicksort algorithm. On some lines it says something like:

```
i := left
```

What does the `:=` stand for? Is it `+=` or a normal `=` ?

FYI: This is the complete pseudocode (German):

```pseudo
 funktion teile(links, rechts)
 i := links 
 // Starte mit j links vom Pivotelement
 j := rechts - 1
 pivot := daten[rechts]

 wiederhole

     // Suche von links ein Element, welches größer als das Pivotelement ist
     wiederhole solange daten[i] ≤ pivot und i < rechts
         i := i + 1
     ende

     // Suche von rechts ein Element, welches kleiner als das Pivotelement ist
     wiederhole solange daten[j] ≥ pivot und j > links
          j := j - 1 
     ende

     falls i < j dann
         tausche daten[i] mit daten[j]
     ende

 solange i < j // solange i an j nicht vorbeigelaufen ist 

 // Tausche Pivotelement (daten[rechts]) mit neuer endgültiger Position (daten[i])

 falls daten[i] > pivot dann
         tausche daten[i] mit daten[rechts]
 ende

 // gib die Position des Pivotelements zurück

 antworte i

ende
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What does the `:=` stand for?

It's an **assignment** operator, derived from the Pascal programming language.

> Is it `+=` or a normal `=`?

`:=` is equivalent to `=`, not to be confused with the **compound assignment** operator (e.g. `+=`).

See [*Variants in assignments and expressions*](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu20.html#x48-550003.7.2) at freepascal.org for a quick reference.

Answer (score 3):

You should read := as "Becomes Equal To".

You would usually have this combination:

```
a := b  #a becomes equal to b
a = b   #if a equals b
```

Or this combination:

```
a = b   #a becomes equal to b
a == b  #if a equals b
```

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to

```
i = "left";
```

in Java etc.. Syntax ":=" is used in programming languages based on Pascal, such as Delphi for example. So it's basically a simple assignment.

Answer (score 2):

If its a pascal style psuedo codes the the symbol is mainly used to asign the value 
reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

that's in Ada as well,

:= is equal to =

and = is equal to ==